# How to integrate by parts with two integrals?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, integration-by-parts

I have a problem I have been trying to integrate using by parts, but I am a bit stuck. We have that $x \geq 0$ and assume $f$ is a smooth function (so we have no issues at $0$) and compact in some interval $f \in C^{[a,b]}(R_{+})$, with $0<a<b<\infty$.

The equation is the following:

\begin{align}
\|(Bf(x))\|_{L^2_{(R_+)}} & =\left(\int_0^\infty \left\lvert\frac{1}{x} \ \int_0^x f(t) \, dt\right\rvert^2 \ dx\right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq\left(\int_0^\infty \left\lvert\frac{1}{x}\right\rvert^{2} \ \left\lvert \int_0^x f(t) \, dt\right\rvert^2 \ dx\right)^{1/2} \\
&=\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dx} \left\lvert\dfrac{-1}{x}\right\rvert \ \left\lvert \int_0^x f(t) \ dt\right\rvert^2 \ dx\right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dx}\left\lvert\dfrac{-1}{x}\right\rvert \ \int_0^x \left\lvert f(t) \right\rvert^{2} \ dt \ dx\right)^{1/2}
\end{align}

Now to solve this I have tried setting $dv=\dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{-1}{x} dt$ and $v=\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{-1}{x}$ (as $x \geq 0$ we can drop the absolute values), with $u=|f(t)|^{2}$ and $du=2\lvert f(t) \rvert dt$.

My other attempt was setting my $dv=\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{-1}{x} dx$ and $v=\dfrac{-1}{x}$ (The dx's cancel when we integrate dv/dx) and setting $u=\int_0^x \lvert f(t) \rvert^2 dt$ and $du=2f(x)\int_0^x \lvert f(t) \rvert \ dt \ dx$. This was to try and solve the whole integral at once. This was the more promising of the two but I can't get an answer that doesn't seem to diverge/become unbounded.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? What should I be setting my $u, du, v$ & $dv$ parts as?

The end result is to prove this is bounded, but with Holder's inequality and density arguments this part should be easy. This intermediate step I am just stuck at. Thank you for any help given!

Comment: You seem to have $\dfrac d {dx} \left| \dfrac 1 x \right| = \left| \dfrac 1 {x^2} \right|$.  That's not right.  In fact $$ \frac d {dx} \left| \frac 1 x \right| = \frac d {dx} \frac 1 x = \frac{-1} {x^2} $$ (where the first equality holds because $x>0$. $\qquad$

Comment: I can change this to $\dfrac{d}{dx} \lvert \dfrac{-1}{x} \rvert = \dfrac{1}{x^{2}}$ with $x \geq 0$ as before. Thanks for the pickup.

Comment: But $\dfrac d {dx} \left| \dfrac{-1} x \right| = \dfrac{-1}{x^2}. \qquad$

Comment: Ah right. Sorry, quite tired. So I should change this to $\dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{-1}{x}= \dfrac{1}{x^{2}} $

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{d}{dx}\lvert\dfrac{1}{x}\rvert \ \int_{0}^{x}\lvert f(t) \rvert^{2} \ dt \ dx$$

Define $K(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\lvert f(t) \rvert^{2} \ dt $. You know what is $K'(x)$ right?(though not required!)

$$\int_0^\infty{d\over dx}\left(|{1\over x}|K(x)\right)dx=\int_0^\infty d\left(|{1\over x}|K(x)\right)=\left[{K(x)\over |x|}\right]_0^\infty$$

If you know $f$ Find $K(x)$ and you are done I think!

Comment: We have that f(t) is undefined, but is smooth so is differentiable. The issue with this is that this diverges as $x \to 0$. 

For the purposes of the question as a whole, it needs to be shown to be a bounded operator (The Bf(x)) in $L^{2}_{R_{+}}$). My teacher hinted that this should result in a constant and use of Holders Inequality (I assume a norm $\lvert\lvert f \rvert \rvert$ in $L^{2}_{R_{+}}$. Thankyou for the help, any help if very appreciated!

Comment: @Tyler_JBL Sorry,(MY bad) but this is all that I can help in this particular question..Sure some more knowledgeable people will respond to your question .Nice question though..+1

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the help anyway :).

Comment: @Tyler_JBL : One should write $\|f\|$ rather than $||f||$.  Notice the conspicuous difference between $||f|| ||g||$ (coded as ||f|| ||g||) and $\|f\|\|g\|$ (coded as \|f\|\|g\|). $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am rather new to LaTeX coding so thanks for that! :)